# With Angular Material Dialog, how to add multiple classes to the dialog?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I can add a custom class to a MatDialog this way:

```
    this.dialog.open(MyGreatDialogComponent, {
      data: myGreatData,
      panelClass: 'my-great-class',
    });
```

Is it possible to add an additional class(es) to a Material dialog?

Comment: add typings to your project so you can immediately see such things panelClass?: string | string[];

Comment: Thanks! Obvious, I guess. Just answered my own question in case someone else comes looking for it, so as not to waste anyone's time, as this wasn't posted anywhere else.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Quite simple to use an array of classes:

```
    this.dialog.open(MyGreatDialogComponent, {
      data: myGreatData,
      panelClass: ['my-great-class', 'my-other-great-class'],
    });
```